# How to make a class printable using Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Can I make a class printable (i.e. `print(x)` works) by overriding its `toString()` method, or is there some other way? `toString()` requires creating a string, which I imagine would involve a lot of wasted concatenation, particularly for nested structures.

It would seem to be more sensible if there was a `print(PrintStream os)` method available, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: So you want to print a string represting the object without creating a string?

Comment: You can always use a `StringBuilder`, but this sounds like a premature optimization.

Comment: Basically I want `print(Object x)` to work. I've changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 2):

+1 @Jeff. You can also use @Canonical with @ToString annotation.

```
import groovy.transform.*

@ToString(includeNames=true, cache=true)
@Canonical class Test{
    String a
    int b
    Book book
}

@ToString(includeNames=true, cache=true)
@Canonical class Book{
    String name
}

Test test = new Test('A', 1, new Book("Groovy In Action"))

//Prints
//Test(a:A, b:1, book:Book(name:Groovy In Action))  

print test
println ""
System.out.print test
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `print` method to metaclass of `Object` if you're using groovy, and something like

```
Object.metaClass.print = { printStream ->
    printStream.print(delegate)
}
```

Though it sounds like you might be worrying about an unnecessary problem. You can use a `StringBuilder` (or groovy's string interpolation) to reduce concatenation. You could also use groovy's [@ToString](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/ToString.html) AST to add a `toString` method and turn on caching so it only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

For non nested structures, `dump()` is a quick solution:

```
class Person { 
    String name
    String surname 
}

p = new Person(name: "John", surname: "Doe")
println p.dump()
// prints <Person@802ef9 name=John surname=Doe>
```